# Invertibility of message passing with invertible parametrization

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, matrix-inverse

Consider the message passing framework defined by, $$f(\boldsymbol{x}_i)= \boldsymbol{x}_i + \sum_{j \neq i} (\boldsymbol{x}_i -\boldsymbol{x}_j) g(\|\boldsymbol{x}_i -\boldsymbol{x}_j\|^2),$$ for $i=1,...,n$ and where $g(\cdot)$ is an invertible function, thus $g^{-1}(\cdot)$ exists. Is it then possible to find the explicit inverse of the function $f$ as defined above?

One way I have tried to approached the problem is defining it in terms of the difference between two $f(\boldsymbol{x}_k)$ and $f(\boldsymbol{x}_l)$ for $k,l=1,...,n$, and $k \neq l$ which gives, $$ f(\boldsymbol{x}_k) - f(\boldsymbol{x}_l) = \boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_l + \sum_{i \neq k} (\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_i) g(|| \boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_i||^2)  - \sum_{j \neq l} (\boldsymbol{x}_l - \boldsymbol{x}_j) g(|| \boldsymbol{x}_l - \boldsymbol{x}_j||^2)$$
$$ \iff f(\boldsymbol{x}_k) - f(\boldsymbol{x}_l) = (\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_l)(1 + 2 g(||\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_l||^2)) + \sum_{i \neq l,k} (\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_i) g(|| \boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_i||^2) - \sum_{j \neq l,k} (\boldsymbol{x}_l - \boldsymbol{x}_j) g(|| \boldsymbol{x}_l - \boldsymbol{x}_j||^2)$$
$$ \iff f(\boldsymbol{x}_k) - f(\boldsymbol{x}_l) = (\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_l)(1 + 2 g(||\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_l||^2)) + \sum_{i \neq l,k}\left[ (\boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_i) g(|| \boldsymbol{x}_k - \boldsymbol{x}_i||^2)-(\boldsymbol{x}_l - \boldsymbol{x}_i) g(|| \boldsymbol{x}_l - \boldsymbol{x}_i||^2)\right]$$

One additional question is, how might one go about exploiting the structure of this matrix for numerical approximation?

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse of the message passing function" and why does it exist?

Comment: I have redefined the question, hopefully it is more clear now. I'm trying to find the inverse of $f$. The inverse of $g$ exists by design, we choose an invertible parameterisation for the non-linear function $g$ such that its inverse exists. I have not (yet) proven the existence of the inverse of $f$, this I'm trying to do by finding an algebraic expression of $f^{-1}.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in general to find $f^{-1}$ explicitly, whatever that might mean. However, I have been unable to find $g$ for which $f$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thank you for giving it a try! With explicitly I mean a mathematical expression for the inverse. I think it is possible to use a numerical solver to approximate the solution, but I'm interested in doing it in an exact manner.

Comment: I have now found an invertible $g$ for which the "the message passing function" is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your request is to provide the presumably unique solution $(\boldsymbol{x}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{x}_n)$ of the system of equations
$$\boldsymbol{y}_i= \boldsymbol{x}_i + \sum_{j \neq i} (\boldsymbol{x}_i -\boldsymbol{x}_j) g(\|\boldsymbol{x}_i -\boldsymbol{x}_j\|^2) \tag{1}\label{1}$$ for $i=1,...,n$, where $g(\cdot)$ is an invertible function and $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{y}_i$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ for some $d$.

However, this system may have more than one solution, and therefore an "inverse of the message passing function" does not exist.

For instance, let $n=2$, $d=1$, and
$$g(z)=
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
 & \frac{10}{9}-z && \text{ if }0\leq z\le\frac{1}{9}, \\
 & \frac12\Big(\frac1{\sqrt{z}}-1\Big) && \text{ if }\frac{1}{9}\leq z\leq
   \frac{1}{4}, \\ 
& \frac{1}{2} e^{1/4-z} && \text{ if }z\ge\frac{1}{4}. 
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\tag{2}\label{2}$$
Then $g$ is continuous and strictly decreasing, and therefore invertible.

Let $x_i:=\boldsymbol{x}_i$ and $y_i:=\boldsymbol{y}_i$. Then for $y_1=1$ and $y_2=0$ any pair $(x_1,x_2)$ of the form
$$(1-t)\Big(\frac23,\frac13\Big)+t\Big(\frac34,\frac14\Big)$$
with $t\in[0,1]$ is a solution of the system \eqref{1}, which thus has
infinitely many solutions, so that an "inverse of the message passing function" does not exist.

---

How was the function $g$ in \eqref{2} constructed? For $n=2$ and $d=1$, the system \eqref{1} can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1&=x_1+(x_1-x_2)g((x_1-x_2)^2), \\ 
y_2&=x_2+(x_2-x_1)g((x_1-x_2)^2).
\end{aligned}
$$
Adding and subtracting these two equations, we rewrite the latter system as
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1+x_2&=y_1+y_2, \\ 
h(x_1-x_2)&=y_1-y_2,
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
where
$$h(u):=u(1+2g(u^2)).$$
So, for the system \eqref{3}, and thus for the system \eqref{1}, to have several solutions, it is enough to choose an invertible $g$ so that $h$ be constant on some nonempty open interval. Letting now $h(u)=1$ for $u$ in some nonempty open subinterval of the interval $(0,\infty)$, we get $g(z)=\frac12(\frac1{\sqrt{z}}-1)$ for $z$ in some other nonempty open subinterval (say $I$) of the interval $(0,\infty)$, so that $g$ is continuous and strictly decreasing on $I$. It remains to extend $g$ to a function that is continuous and strictly decreasing on the entire interval $[0,\infty)$. Thus, we get \eqref{2}.

Comment: Thank you for helping out!

Comment: @PonderingPolynomial : I am glad this was of help. In such a case, [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) may be relevant.